# A UICollection Crash in iOS7, crash diagnosis 'Possible zombie in call: -[NSIndexPath release]'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

My Companies's app still supports iOS7 now, but we got a report of crash in iOS7 about UICollectionView in few views. These crashes show the same, like this:

```
"process": {
        "last_dealloced_nsexception": {
            "reason": "layout constraints are not satisfiable.", 
            "name": "NSGenericException", 
            "address": 407334848
        }
    }, 
    "crashThreadSymbolList": [
        "objc_msgSend (in libobjc.A.dylib_7.0.4) + 6", 
        "-[_UICollectionViewItemKey dealloc] (in UIKit_7.0.4) + 41", 
        "objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) (in libobjc.A.dylib_7.0.4) + 175", 
        "(anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) (in libobjc.A.dylib_7.0.4) + 359", 
        "_CFAutoreleasePoolPop (in CoreFoundation_7.0.4) + 17", 
        "_wrapRunLoopWithAutoreleasePoolHandler (in UIKit_7.0.4) + 37", 
        "__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation_7.0.4) + 21", 
        "__CFRunLoopDoObservers (in CoreFoundation_7.0.4) + 287", 
        "CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation_7.0.4) + 559", 
        "CFRunLoopRunInMode (in CoreFoundation_7.0.4) + 107", 
        "GSEventRunModal (in GraphicsServices_7.0.4) + 139", 
        "UIApplicationMain (in UIKit_7.0.4) + 1137", 
        "main (in Jdipad_3.9.3_9743_AS) (main.m:41)"
    ]
```

It seems to be a crash typically in iOS7 for we just got the report about it iOS7, and I searched a lot on Google, but still confused and do not know how to fix it. Is there any one have encountered this problem?

Comment: it seems that reason of crash is constraint. Some where constraints is being broken in your collection view.

Comment: Thanks! But How can I locate the views in which the contraints broken? It involve a lot of views.

Comment: You can try to use View Debuger for that